# Reading lines from text file and add to List<string>

Tags: c#, windows

I'm working in a project that I need read lines in a .txt file and push this lines into a List.

In my first prototype, in WPF,  I used this very simple code to do this:

```
private static List<string> fileLines = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt").ToList();
```

However, now I am working at a Windows Phone 8.1 version and I can't do that in this way.

For now, my research come this code but no successfully:

```
public static List<string> fileLines = LoadingLines();

public static async Task<List<string>> LoadingLines()
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("WordList.txt");
    IList<string> text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile);

    return text;
}
```

Some problem that I have with this code is that I don't know if this returns a List where each line of the file is one element and if I try assign a Task> type to a List I have this error: Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Maybe this code are totally wrong to what I need. Again, what I need is just read a .txt file in my packaged app and turn each line in an element of fileLines List. Obviously, after, I need access this List out of the method.

Comment: What exactly does `no successfully` mean? What failed and where?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working as you expected. Do you get any errors, is the result different from what you expected? Please [edit] your question to add the relevant details that may allow us to help you find out what is wrong and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701475.aspx) a call to `ReadLinesAsync` will return `IAsyncOperation<IVector>`, i.e. when you await it, this will return an `IVector<string>`. For this type, documentation states:

> Represents a random-access collection of elements. .NET:  This
>   interface appears to .NET code as `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`
>   due to .NET language projection. In any case where a Windows Runtime
>   type has implemented IVector, .NET code can use the APIs of
>   `IList<T>` instead.

So this line in your code should work fine

```
IList<string> text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile);
```

The problem is that `text` is of the type `IList<string>`, but the return type for your method is `List<string>`. You cannot assign an `IList<string>` instance to the return value of type `List<string>`.

To fix this, you can use one of the following two options:

1. Change the signature of your method to

   `public static async Task<IList<string>> LoadingLines()`
2. Convert your methods result to a `List<string>` when you return it:

   ```
   return text.ToList();
   ```

When you use the result returned from your method, you also must do so with the `await` keyword, so this line:

```
public static List<string> fileLines = LoadingLines();
```

Will not work correctly, because `LoadingLines` returns a `Task<List<string>>`. You cannot asynchronously load into a static member variable. If you want this to work (making minimal changes to your code)<sup>1</sup> what you can do is the following:

Remove this line:

```
public static List<string> fileLines = LoadingLines();
```

And replace it with:

```
private readonly static Task<List<string>> loadLinesTask = LoadingLines();

public static async Task<List<string>> GetLinesAsync()
{
    return await _loadLinesTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

You can then call `GetLinesAsync()` in other "async" methods. If you need to call this in methods that are not marked as `async`, you cannot use `await` and (using `MyClass` for the class with these methods) you will have to do this to get the list of lines:

```
var lines = MyClass.GetLinesAsync().Result;
```

<sup>1</sup> There are better ways to do this, but to discuss that that would go beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @TiagoZontag, you are welcome. If this answered your question, you may want to mark it as the answer, so that your question can be removed from the "unanswered questions" list. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Alex, thank you but not works because I need assign the return value to the List<string> fileLines. Some another conversion remains needed: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: You're getting a task as a result, assign the .Result() of the object instead. If your method has the async modifier as suggested in the answer, await it - var result = await LoadingLines()

Comment: @TiagoZontag I added additional information on the second error you are getting, and how you can solve that.

Comment: Thank you @Alex, but I will continue looking for this better way because I think that what I have until now are very bad. Just say me if I can do that without async method. Thank you again.

Comment: New Error: #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the text file to your project.  Right-click it, choose Properties and set the action property to "embedded resource".
2. Access it as follows.  The resource name is fully qualified name, meaning the namespace is included.  (Ex. - "MyCompany.Project.Resouces.fileName.txt").

   ```
       var list = new List<string>();
       var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
       var resourceName = "XYZ.ABC.Resources.MyTextFile.txt";

       using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
       {
           while (!reader.EndOfStream)
           {
               list.Add(reader.ReadLine());
           }
       }
       return list;
   ```